# How to fix a shortcode to display its content in the correct location?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a shortcode that will display some information based on the 
 [Schema.org Person Type](http://schema.org/Person).

I created this simple test shortcode that will echo one phrase. The phrase is: `Personal Info`. Here is the code:

```
function add_schema_person_shortcode() {
        echo '<div class="schema_person_microdata_container">';
            echo '<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">'; 
                echo '<h3>'; echo 'Personal Info'; echo '</h3>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'schema-person-shortcode', 'add_schema_person_shortcode');
```

My problem is that the phrase `Personal Info` is displayed on top of all content, even if there is content above the shortcode.

[Please refer to this test post by clicking here.](https://audio.coptic-treasures.com/shortcode-test/)

The post content is:

```
<p>this is text written ABOVE the shortcode.</p>
[schema-person-shortcode]
<p>this is text written below the shortcode.</p>
```

However, what is displayed in the front end is:
[image]

As I don't have any special code to force the shortcode content to display at the page top, I am unable to determine where is the error.

I'd appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction on how to fix this problem and get the shortcode content to display in its correct location.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I got an excellent answer from @Andrew Schultz below, but it works for me only when I want to display text. I had added a dummy code to my original question to make it easy.

However, my full code has if statements, so I am pasting the full code below, to help getting a solution when there are if statements in the code.

Thanks.

```
function add_schema_person_shortcode() {
    if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ar') { 

        if( function_exists( 'types_render_field' ) ){

            $author_info = array_filter( array (
                    'honorificPrefix' => types_render_field( "schema-person-honorific-prefix", array () ),
                    'givenName'       => types_render_field( "schema-person-given-name", array () ),
                    'familyName'      => types_render_field( "schema-person-family-name", array () ),
                    'honorificSuffix' => types_render_field( "schema-person-honorific-suffix", array () ),
                    ) );

            $author_additional_name = array_filter( array (
                    'additionalName' => types_render_field( "schema-person-additional-name", array () ),
                    ) );        

            $person_monastic_name = array_filter( array (
                    'additionalName' => types_render_field( "schema-person-monastic-name", array () ),
                    ) );        

            $person_date_of_birth = array_filter( array (
                    'birthDate' => types_render_field( "schema-person-date-of-birth", array () ),
                    ) );

            $person_place_of_birth = array_filter( array (
                    'birthPlace' => types_render_field( "schema-person-place-of-birth", array () ),
                    ) );        

                if ( ! empty( $author_info ) ) {

                    echo '<div class="schema_person_microdata_container">';
                        echo '<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">'; 
                        echo '<h3>'; echo 'كارت التعريف بالشخصية'; echo '</h3>';
                        echo '<table class="schema_book_microdata_table">';
                            echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<th class="schema-book-table-initial-column">'; echo 'البيانات'; echo '</th>';
                                echo '<th>';echo 'التفاصيل'; echo '</th>';
                            echo '</tr>';                   
                            echo '<tr><td>الأسم</td><td>';
                                foreach ( $author_info as $prop => $value ) {
                                printf( '<span itemprop="%s"> %s </span>', $prop, $value );
                                }
                                echo '</span></td></tr>';


                            if ( ! empty( $author_additional_name ) ) {
                                echo '<tr><td>الأسم قبل الرسامة</td><td>';
                                foreach ( $author_additional_name as $prop => $value ) {
                                printf( '<span itemprop="%s"> %s </span>', $prop, $value );
                                }
                                echo '</span></td></tr>';
                            }

                            if ( ! empty( $person_monastic_name ) ) {
                                echo '<tr><td>الأسم الرهباني</td><td>';
                                foreach ( $person_monastic_name as $prop => $value ) {
                                printf( '<span itemprop="%s"> %s </span>', $prop, $value );
                                }
                                echo '</span></td></tr>';
                            }

                            if ( ! empty( $person_date_of_birth ) ) {
                                echo '<tr><td>تاريخ الميلاد</td><td>';
                                foreach ( $person_date_of_birth as $prop => $value ) {
                                printf( '<span itemprop="%s"> %s </span>', $prop, $value );
                                }
                                echo '</span></td></tr>';
                            }

                            if ( ! empty( $person_place_of_birth ) ) {
                                echo '<tr><td>محل الميلاد</td><td>';
                                foreach ( $person_place_of_birth as $prop => $value ) {
                                printf( '<span itemprop="%s"> %s </span>', $prop, $value );
                                }
                                echo '</span></td></tr>';
                            }



                        echo '</table>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
        }

    }
}
add_shortcode( 'schema-person-shortcode', 'add_schema_person_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcode function needs to return something not echo the text.

```
function add_schema_person_shortcode() {
    $content = '<div class="schema_person_microdata_container">';
    $content .= '<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">'; 
    $content .= '<h3>Personal Info</h3>';
    $content .= '</div>';
    $content .= '</div>';

    return $content;
}

add_shortcode( 'schema-person-shortcode', 'add_schema_person_shortcode');
```

Here I illustrate the use of PHP output buffer to collect all the echo output then capture it and return it at the end of the function.

```
function add_schema_person_shortcode() {
    ob_start();

    if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ar') { 

        if( function_exists( 'types_render_field' ) ){

            $author_info = array_filter( array (
                    'honorificPrefix' => types_render_field( "schema-person-honorific-prefix", array () ),
                    'givenName'       => types_render_field( "schema-person-given-name", array () ),
                    'familyName'      => types_render_field( "schema-person-family-name", array () ),
                    'honorificSuffix' => types_render_field( "schema-person-honorific-suffix", array () ),
                    ) );

            $author_additional_name = array_filter( array (
                    'additionalName' => types_render_field( "schema-person-additional-name", array () ),
                    ) );        

            $person_monastic_name = array_filter( array (
                    'additionalName' => types_render_field( "schema-person-monastic-name", array () ),
                    ) );        

            $person_date_of_birth = array_filter( array (
                    'birthDate' => types_render_field( "schema-person-date-of-birth", array () ),
                    ) );

            $person_place_of_birth = array_filter( array (
                    'birthPlace' => types_render_field( "schema-person-place-of-birth", array () ),
                    ) );        

                if ( ! empty( $author_info ) ) {

                    echo '<div class="schema_person_microdata_container">';
                        echo '<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">'; 
                        echo '<h3>'; echo 'كارت التعريف بالشخصية'; echo '</h3>';
                        echo '<table class="schema_book_microdata_table">';
                            echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<th class="schema-book-table-initial-column">'; echo 'البيانات'; echo '</th>';
                                echo '<th>';echo 'التفاصيل'; echo '</th>';
                            echo '</tr>';                   
                            echo '<tr><td>الأسم</td><td>';
                                foreach ( $author_info as $prop => $value ) {
                                printf( '<span itemprop="%s"> %s </span>', $prop, $value );
                                }
                                echo '</span></td></tr>';


                            if ( ! empty( $author_additional_name ) ) {
                                echo '<tr><td>الأسم قبل الرسامة</td><td>';
                                foreach ( $author_additional_name as $prop => $value ) {
                                printf( '<span itemprop="%s"> %s </span>', $prop, $value );
                                }
                                echo '</span></td></tr>';
                            }

                            if ( ! empty( $person_monastic_name ) ) {
                                echo '<tr><td>الأسم الرهباني</td><td>';
                                foreach ( $person_monastic_name as $prop => $value ) {
                                printf( '<span itemprop="%s"> %s </span>', $prop, $value );
                                }
                                echo '</span></td></tr>';
                            }

                            if ( ! empty( $person_date_of_birth ) ) {
                                echo '<tr><td>تاريخ الميلاد</td><td>';
                                foreach ( $person_date_of_birth as $prop => $value ) {
                                printf( '<span itemprop="%s"> %s </span>', $prop, $value );
                                }
                                echo '</span></td></tr>';
                            }

                            if ( ! empty( $person_place_of_birth ) ) {
                                echo '<tr><td>محل الميلاد</td><td>';
                                foreach ( $person_place_of_birth as $prop => $value ) {
                                printf( '<span itemprop="%s"> %s </span>', $prop, $value );
                                }
                                echo '</span></td></tr>';
                            }



                        echo '</table>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
        }

    }

    $function_output = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return $function_output;
}
add_shortcode( 'schema-person-shortcode', 'add_schema_person_shortcode');
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Schultz. Your solution works perfectly when I have text only to display. I have edited my question to show the full code, which has a lot of php functions. how to wrap it in `$content`? thanks

Comment: @AtefWagih I've updated my answer to include an output buffering solution.  Just to let you know for future questions, please don't change your question after already receiving an answer as you have changed the scope of the requirements which is frustrating for people trying to help.  Hope this fulfils your new requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrew Schults. The solution worked perfectly. Very much appreciated, and sorry for the edit. I will take this into consideration next time.

Comment: @AtefWagih not a problem I'm just letting you know that other people won't be so generous ;)

Comment: would you mind looking at this question, please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621836/how-to-create-a-shortcode-edit-a-function-to-solve-the-conflict-between-bootstra thanks.