# How to create a shortcode/edit a function to solve the conflict between Bootstrap and wpautop in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, shortcode

Following on from my previously unsolved question [How to show Bootstrap Buttons inline instead of one per line in Wordpress Specifically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115844/how-to-show-bootstrap-buttons-inline-instead-of-one-per-line-in-wordpress-specif)
 and after extensive research in this point, I found out that that there is a conflict between Wordpress and Bootstrap.

Wordpress simplified the text editing process by introducing invisible line breaks `< /br>` after each line. When Using Bootstrap elements (e..g buttons) with Wordpress, a line break `< /br>` gets introduced after each button code, leading them to appear one button per line, likr this screenshot:
[image]

The only solution I found (which appears as an edit in my other question referred to above), is to add this function:
`remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );`

However, this function while it solved the Bootstrap problem, forces me to write full html on all text of all posts, otherwise the text will appear as one unformmatted block.

As a workaround for this problem, I thought of putting the Bootstrap components in a div tag, then either creating a shortcode that applies this filter to the content of of the divtag, or create a function that targets this div tag without the need to add a shortcode.

As a start, I created this shortcode function, but it didn't do anything:
(yes it doesn't have a div tag specified, but I was testing if the shortcode will work, but it didn't).

```
    function stop_wpautop(){
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
}
    add_shortcode( 'stop-wpautop', 'stop_wpautop');
```

I also tried replacing `the_content` with a div tag class name that I wrapped the Bootstrap components with, but it didn't work too.

```
    function stop_wpautop(){
    remove_filter( 'bootstrap-components', 'wpautop' );
}
    add_shortcode( 'stop-wpautop', 'stop_wpautop');
```

Finally, I added the filter straight without a shortcode, but it didn't work too:

`remove_filter( 'bootstrap-components', 'wpautop' );`

So obviously, I am writing the function wrong. Can someone please guide me as to what's wrong, or any suggestion to limit the effect of the `wpautop` to a certain div tag only?

***EDIT***
I can add the Bootstrap code in a custom field then show the custom field contents if this will make things easier, but I still don't know how to replace `the_content` with the custom field name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be an issue relating to your theme.  I created a shortcode and inserted it into the WYSIWYG editor in "Text" editor mode and the buttons appear inline.  http://www.openscreenshot.com/#/i/S1p-0sgsM

Comment: It's definitely a wordpress issue. I confirmed this over 6 we installation with countless themes on different servers. If you edited your post, changed it back to visual and saved,  it will show vertically

Comment: I found out previously that the only way to get it to work is to paste the buttons code in one line. But if you copied the buttons code from the Bootstrap documentation, it will show vertically, because the documentation has one button per line.

Comment: I always use the text editor, never use the WYSIWYG because you never can guarantee the formatting of your html.  However, I just tested my shortcode, saved the document in visual editor and the buttons still formatted correctly with the default WordPress 2016 theme.  Have you got an page builder plugins installed?

Comment: Hi @AndrewSchultz. when you say "tested my shortcode", where is your shortcode that you are referring to? I am not using any page builders. can you please share a screenshot with your code in the text area? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that I am using to output the test buttons.

```
add_shortcode('show_boot_buttons', 'func_show_buttons');

function func_show_buttons( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'class' => 'btn',
            'text' => 'Press Me',
        ), $atts, 'show_boot_buttons' );

    return '<button type="button" class="btn ' . esc_html( $atts['class'] ) .'">'. esc_html( $atts['text'] ). '</button>';
}
```

You can insert a button with the following code example.

```
[show_boot_buttons class="btn-primary" text="Press This"]
```

Comment: @AndrewSchulz. Do you know that the problem exists in Wordpress even without Bootstrap. Bootstrap only adds the styling. If you added Bootstrap code and did not import the css sheet, the problem will still appear. Here is a proof, [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) can you please copy the code from this page, paste it in a new post in text mode, publish it and see?. Here is a direct copy& paste of that code to a fresh installation I did now. [link](https://audio.coptic-treasures.com/bootstrappp/). Here is how it looks in the baceknd [link](https://prntscr.com/j09w5f)

Comment: @AtefWagih I'm not using Bootstrap at all just the theme's styling.

Comment: Exactly right. That's what I highlighted in my last comment. the problem is not exclusive between Bootstrap and WP. The problem appears if you added button codes line by line. the only way to show the buttons inline like this [link](https://prnt.sc/j0a1dp) is to add the code like this [link](https://prntscr.com/j0a1uh) which is inconvenient if you have many buttons. is there a way to write a function to apply the remove filter only on a specific div tag?

Comment: @AtefWagih even after adding bootstrap styling the buttons still appear inline. http://www.openscreenshot.com/#/i/SJgOaW-sM

Comment: @AtefWagih you must have a problem when you've edited the post and inserted the shortcode.  Edit the post in text mode to see if the problem persists.  I can see in your web page that your buttons are surrounded by <p> tags.

Comment: I am not saying that your shortcode doesn't work. I am just trying to find a solution without having to create a separate shortcode each time I want to add a button. the problem relates definitely to the `wpautop` function. If you inspected the buttons on [my page here](https://audio.coptic-treasures.com/bootstrappp/) you will find a `<br>` after each button. I already applied the `wpautop` removing function and it fixed the problem, but it forces me to write full html for everything, so I am trying to write a function that limits the removal to certain div tag that I put around the buttons.

Comment: @AtefWagih Create one shortcode and use parameters to feed to it. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168135/discussion-between-atef-wagih-and-andrew-schultz).