# Function to remove wpautop from a specific div tag

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress has a built in filter called `wpautop` that facilitates adding text in the "visual" mode. This function adds `<p>` and `<br>` to the paragraphs to provide the "what you see if what you get" output.
[Details about this function can be found here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)

The above link also provides a function to remove this filter:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

However, this function removes the filter from all the content when specifying `the_content`.

I need to modify the code to target a certain `div` that has a certain class.

I wrapped the text I want to exclude the filter from with a `div class="exclude-wpautop">` and modified the function to be:

```
remove_filter( 'exclude-wpautop', 'wpautop' );
```

But this didn't work.

Also, [As I mentioned in my other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621836/how-to-create-a-shortcode-edit-a-function-to-solve-the-conflict-between-bootstra/), I tried creating a shortcode to target this `div` tag, but it didn't work too.

```
function stop_wpautop(){
remove_filter( 'exclude-wpautop', 'wpautop' );
}
add_shortcode( 'stop-wpautop', 'stop_wpautop');
```

Is there a way to target a specific `div` and apply the function to it? or create a shortcode that when it wraps the text, it stops the effect of the `wpautop` for this portion of text only?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/248814/strip-only-specific-tags-like-p-but-keep-other-tags-like-br?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

First, the first argument to remove_filter is a filter name not class names of HTML elements.

As wpautop() will not process HTML `<pre>` elements I would replace your

```
<div class="exclude-wpautop">...</div>
```

with

```
<pre class="exclude-wpautop">...</pre>
```

You can then change the `<pre>` HTML element to a `<div>` element with a filter that runs **after** wpautop()

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'rewrite_pre_exclude_wpautop', 11 );
```

where rewrite_pre_exclude_wpautop() simply replaces your temporary `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags with `<div>` and `</div>` tags;

rewrite_pre_exclude_wpautop() looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'rewrite_pre_exclude_wpautop', 11 );
function rewrite_pre_exclude_wpautop( $content ) {
    $pre = '<pre class="exclude-wpautop">';
    $len = strlen( $pre );
    $pos = 0;
    while ( ( $pos = strpos( $content, $pre, $pos ) ) !== FALSE ) {
        $content = substr_replace( $content, '<div>', $pos, ? );
        $pos += ?;
        $pos = strpos( $content, '</pre>', $pos );
        $content = substr_replace( $content, '</div>', $pos, ? );
        $pos += ?;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I added the `add_filter` line to my `functions.php` and replaced the `div` with the `pre`, but the end result is [this warning](http://prntscr.com/j0piir). can you please elaborate on what I should be doing? thanks.

Comment: You have to write the function rewrite_pre_exclude_wpautop. It is not a predefined function. Do you know PHP?

Comment: No I haven't written it. I know very very basic php. I thought that this is a predefined php function. can you please guide me as to what to do to write it? any references? thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know how to use the PHP functions strpos() and substr_replace()? You need to use these functions to find the <pre> tags and replace them with <div> tags. I think it can be done with 7 lines of PHP. I think you should make the effort to write this yourself. I will help you further if necessary. It is pretty elementary PHP albeit it does require careful tracking of character positions so it will take some work to get it right but that is work you shoul do for yourself.

Comment: Actually, 14 lines of PHP code. Code is elementary but requires careful consideration of string offsets maybe difficult for someone not good at math.

Comment: Thanks @magenta. I don't stand a chance of writing such a complex 14 lines of php code. I guess I will need to hire a developer to do so...

Comment: If you try I will help you as necessary. Are you mathematically challenged?

Comment: I have appended the code with some question marks (?) as I think you need to make at least some effort as Stack Overflow should not be used as a 'coding service'.

Comment: thanks a lot. I understand that it is not a coding service. that's why I said that I will search for a developer when things got above me. I will try in the code you gave me and let you know the progress. thanks heaps.

Comment: I will help you as much as needed as long as you make a sincere effort on your side. Please feel free to ask any question. I will my do my best to help you understand. It is more important that you develop your skill then just getting a ready made solution.

Comment: @MagentaCuda isn't enough to write `echo str_replace(
    array('<pre>', '</pre>'),
    array('<code>', '</code>'),
    $your_html_with_pre_tags
);`?

Answer (score 0):

How to exclude your content blocks from adding tag `<p>` with wpautop:

In your posts you can add tag `<pre>` that avoids to add tag `<p>` to the content inside of `<pre>`.

Example:

```
<pre> your any content and any html tags, without adding tag p </pre>
```

Then add this code below to your functions.php to delete all tags `<pre>` from your content:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'al_wputopfix', 999);

//AL wputop fix
function al_wputopfix ($content) {
if ( stripos( $content, '<pre>' ) !== false ){
$content = preg_replace( '~<pre>|</pre>~', '', $content );
}
return $content;
}
```